# Need help to interpret this. I am a beginner in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I been searching for ages about IEnumerable online but they are all in the program.cs file.

Can anyone please tell me what is it at the below code?

```
namespace customBank.Interfaces
{
    public class Bank : customBank // the bank take the format of customBank as interface.
    {
        public IEnumerable<IStatementRow> GetMiniStatement(IAccount account)
    }
}
```

Comment: In a nutshell, it is telling you that Bank has implemented customBank. Bank has a method GetMiniStatement which takes account as input and provides enumerable.

Comment: You should search `C# IEnumerable` on google.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: This code is incomplete. My guess is that the exercise that has been provided here is to create a method body for the stub. the exercise is probably asking you to get a list of statement rows for the account and return them.

Comment: The code looks strange because they're passing around interfaces as parameters and objects. Many people don't know that you can declare an interface as a variable, and set an object to it that subscribes to that interface.

Comment: Thank for you all your replies. Now I understand that it is method which pass the account object. The question for this part is to get last 5 transactions, so I have no idea how to get the information.

I am a ruby person. Usually this will be like account.transactions.last(5) which is an associations but it is not in this case.

Answer (score 3):

IEnumerable is a list of "things" that you can loop through. In this situation, it is a list of IStatementRow things.

A list of IStatementRow things is returned when the GetMiniStatement function is called.

Comment: Thank you very much..

The question is asking me to return a list of 5 latest transaction. Sorry that I am not C# person, in Ruby: it will be like account.transactions.last(5).

Comment: If you have your IEnumerable<IStatementRow> object in memory, then you can sort them in descending order, and take five of them... IEnumerable<IStatementRow> list = GetMiniStatement(arg1).OrderByDescending(x => x.FieldName).Take(5)

Answer (score -3):

See: [IEnumerable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also see: [Interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

Once you read that you will understand pretty well whats happening on your code.